# Creating a Types Declaration file for an existing library

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

I'm working towards building a Type Declaration file for an existing JavaScript library. Since I have no experience with creating declaration files I've created a simple test project that emulates the library I ultimately want to create a declaration file for. I have some TypeScript experience and I've read through the TypeScript documentation on declaration files but I'm struggling to get my test project working. When I try to compile I get the error:

`File '<...>/test.d.ts' is not a module.`

My test project structure is as follows:

```
Project
    ├ index.ts
    ├ test.d.ts
    ┕ test.js
```

**test.js**

```
class MyClassA {
    constructor(){}
    
    static staticMethodA(x, y) {
        console.log(`staticMethodA(${x}, ${y})`);
    }
    
    regularMethodA(z) {
        return `regularMethodA(${z})`;
    }
}

class MyClassB {
    constructor(){}
    
    regularMethodB(q) {
        return `regularMethodB(${q})`;
    }
}

var classes = {
    ClassA: MyClassA,
    MyClassB: MyClassB
};

exports.classes = classes;
```

**test.d.ts**

```
declare module "test" {
    class MyClassA {
        constructor();
        public static staticMethodA(x: number, y: number): void;
        public regularMethodA(z: string): string;
    }

    class MyClassB {
        constructor();
        public regularMethodB(q: string): string;
    }

    export interface classes {
        ClassA: MyClassA;
        MyClassB: MyClassB;
    }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import {MyClassA} from "./test.js";

const foo: MyClassA = new MyClassA();

console.log(foo.regularMethodA("Test"));
```

I don't know why I'm getting the `not a module` error. I'm assuming there's a problem with my `test.d.ts` file but I don't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include the `.js` extension when performing imports. Try `import { MyClassA } from "./test" }`